# How do I get the Severity value from a HKSample of the Health app

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I want to show headache data from the Health app.
From the HealtStore I get an array of [HKSamles].
How do I get the HKCategoryValueSeverity?

From each sample I can get the startDate, endDate, etc.

The sampleType is HKCategoryTypeIdentifierHeadache.
At the moment I use the first character of the debugDescription of the HKSample as a Number for the HKCategoryValueSeverity.rawValue

I have this debugDescription for a HealthKit HKSample.
So in the following description the severity rawValue is 4 -> .severe

`4 1F6AED01-EB6A-4ADE-94C0-64F3F8B018BB " HKCategoryTypeIdentifierHeadache" (1), "iPhone13,3" (14.4) (2021-03-13 22:18:57 +0100 - 2021-03-13 22:28:57 +0100)`

Comment: Simple!

let severity = item.value(forKey: "value") as! Int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample you get the query is of type HKCategorySample which has a property value. See

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcategorysample?language=objc

For headache, like other symptom types, value is an enum of type HKCategoryValueSeverity

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcategorytypeidentifierheadache?language=objc
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcategoryvalueseverity?language=objc

You can compare value to the list of possible enums to get severity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem was: I could not find the Key of value(forKey: "value") to get the Severity in the Apple documentation. Found it with some trial and error: ```let severity = item.value(forKey: "value") as! Int```  Which returns the value I was looking for.